# Problem sorting bibliography by author in a Django model with ManyToMany relationship while preserving proper author order

Tags: django, sorting, manytomanyfield

I'm very new to Django so please forgive this question if the answer is obvious. I have struggled with it for several days and finally found a workaround but I'm certain there has to be a better way. Here's the issue in a nutshell: I'm building a Django web site to lists books on various topics. The main listing should be sorted alphabetically by author and that part is easy.  Call this 'vertical sorting'. However, quite a few of the books have multiple authors and the ordering of authors for a given book is *not* alphabetical: it could be anything, e.g., Author B and Author A instead of Author A and Author B. Call this 'horizontal sorting."

The problem is that the default SelectMultiple widget for Django forms allows you to select multiple items but doesn't allow you to specify the ordering. It always comes out alphabetically. I found a way to force the ordering I want but this had the undesirable effect of breaking the vertical sorting.

Here's a snippet of my Publication model:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    """A class to define publication fields"""

    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='publications')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    [snip...]
```

where the Author model (not shown) is sorted alphabetically by lastName, firstName

In views.py I'm doing this:

```
def dbBib(request):
    """Show all Publications"""
    pubs = Publication.objects.all().order_by('author')
    [snip...]
```

This combination, when sent to the template, produces a bibliographic listing of books sorted by author (vertically) but with some of the book authors listed in the wrong order.

My first attempt to fix the horizontal sorting was to add a new field to the model, "author_sorting," so that if I entered "2,3,1", say, it would result in an author ordering of Author B, Author C, Author A, as specified, instead of the default A, B, C. That works but destroys the vertical sorting in that the view is still ordering as if Author A was first in the list.

My solution to THAT issue was to add yet another field to the model,"first author," wherein I specify the first author and use that as the sort field in views.py. But now I have to add another property when entering data, in addition to entering the full author list in the SelectMultiple control *and* the author_sorting field mentioned above.  This works but there has to be an easier way!!

Along the way I had to come up with another kludge to remove duplicate listings (or triplicates when there are three authors, etc.) but that's a topic for another day...

Comment: Something like https://github.com/incuna/django-orderable might work for you. You could add a through model for `Publication.author`, make it orderable and then use an orderable formset instead of a SelectMultiple form field

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Iain. I've checked out django-orderable and followed their recipe as best as I can but I'm not getting the sort control on my author field the way it appears in their demo graphic. I'm sure that I'm messing up in the admin configuration because their guidance on that is a little vague for a newbie. Anyway, I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

The tip that Iain provided got me on the right track.  I didn't use the django-orderable solution because I was unsure about how to implement the admin parts of it but I did find a similar approach at https://github.com/alsoicode/django-admin-sortable. The documentation in this repo is so thorough that even a newcomer like me had no trouble implementing the solution.  It really helped that they provided a complete working sample project that I was able to adapt to my problem just by adding a few model classes. Especially helpful was the explicit example about how to use this in a ManyToMany relationship. Thanks again!